# How to write a test of two numbers?

Tags: java, junit

I'm not sure if I'm right with that. I have a normal function where I scan two numbers and add them together.

Now, I want to write a test where I can check if the function is right.

My function to add:

```java
public class adding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number1;
        int number2;
        int sum;
        Scanner scan;
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        scan.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());

        System.out.println("Please give the first number: ");
        number1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please give the second number: ");
        number2 = scan.nextInt();
        
        sum = number1 + number2;
        System.out.println("Sum of the two numbers: " + sum);

    }
}
```

The test function:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
public class addingTest {
    @Before
    public void testing() throws Exception {
    
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        int sum = 4+5;
        assertEquals(sum, 9);
    }
}
```

Comment: your test is pointless, since it doesn't test your actual code. write your code in testable units (methods) and test those.

Comment: What do you mean.. I´m new in it @Stultuske

Comment: @basics_: unit testing assumes that code is structured into *units* that have clearly delineated responsibilities. You have only a single unit (the `main` method) that does everything, including reading from the user, doing the calculation and outputting the result. It's also written in a way that you can't change where the input comes from and where the output goes to, so it's not very testable. A first step would be to extract the actual calculation into a simple method. Then **that** method can easily be tested by calling it with known values and verifying the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your test is doing nothing. Well, not nothing but it tests if `4+5` is `9` which is true, but this doesn't get you anywhere.

In the most basic form, unit tests are tests which verify the functionality of a "unit" of your class. That means a part of your code that has its own responsibility and that is tested in isolation from any other dependencies.

Right now you only have a `main` method and nothing that can be tested. What you should do instead is to extract the "logic" into methods. You're trying to test if two numbers are added correctly, so extract that into a method:

```
public static int add(int number1, int number2) {
    return number1 + number2;
}
```

Integrate the method into your code:

```
public class Rechenprogramm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        ...

        System.out.println("Please give the first number: ");
        number1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please give the second number: ");
        number2 = scan.nextInt();
    
        sum = add(number1, number2);
        ...
    }

    public static int add(int number1, int number2) {
        return number1 + number2;
    }
}
```

Now that you have extracted the functionality, it *can* be tested in isolation in the form of a unit test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    int number1 = 4;
    int number2 = 5;
    int actualSum = Rechenprogramm.add(number1, number2);

    assertEquals(9, actualSum);
}
```